# xpath query (in Hive) only returns first instance of an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, hive

I have a xpath query (using hive) where I want to display all book node id attribute values.

My Xpath statement looks like this:

```
Select xpath_string (bookxml, '/catalog/book/@id') from bookxml;
```

When I run this in hive, it only returns the first book id and not all of the values. Can you suggest a change where I could return all book id's?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Hive at all, but I was interested in the question so I googled for "Hive xpath_string" and the summary of the first hit was

> Each function returns a specific Hive type given the XPath expression:
>   xpath returns a Hive array of strings. xpath_string returns a string.
>   xpath_boolean returns ...

So it took me about 2 seconds to discover that you want to use the xpath function rather than the xpath_string function.

I sometimes wonder whether there are people who turn to StackOverflow before they turn to the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said problem is with xpath_string function.

I have created small sample file like this one

```
<catalog><book id="1"></book><book id="2"></book></catalog>
<catalog><book id="3"></book><book id="5"></book></catalog>
```

I have created external table around this file like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE books (books_xml string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/home/dino/Downloads/books';
```

When you run query with xpath_string function you get just first IDs    like shown bellow:

```
hive> select xpath_string(books_xml, '/catalog/book/@id') from books;
```

RESULT:

```
Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
OK
1
3
Time taken: 3.765 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

If you run same query with xpath function you get these results:

```
hive> select xpath(books_xml, '/catalog/book/@id') from books;
```

RESULT:

```
Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
OK
["1","2"]
["3","5"]
Time taken: 4.512 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: Dino, I actually need to produce the first result that you show that uses the xpath_string. I want to show the 1 and 3 on separate rows. However, when I use your example CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE code, hive returns an error message. It submits the map reduce job and then FAILED: execution error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask. I am using the HDInsight developer preview 0.8 release developed by Hortonworks for Microsoft. Not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: David, I'm using 0.11 Apache Hive distro and it is in local mode. This problem which u are experiencing is related to configuration of environment. Can you describe how your environment looks like? Are you running in cluster mode or standalone? Also if you could find logs of task which was run to extract real error message from it ?

Answer (score 0):

Describe Function Extended makes life much easier. This definitely makes things clear:

**Describe function extended path_string;**

xpath_string(xml, xpath) - Returns the text contents of the first xml node that matches the xpath expression
Example:

```
SELECT xpath_string('<a><b>b</b><c>cc</c></a>','a/c') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>'cc'
SELECT xpath_string('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b></a>','a/b') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>'b1'
SELECT xpath_string('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b></a>','a/b[2]') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>'b2'
SELECT xpath_string('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b></a>','a') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>'b1b2'
```

**Describe Function Extended path;**

xpath(xml, xpath) - Returns a string array of values within xml nodes that match the xpath expression
Example:

```
SELECT xpath('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b><b>b3</b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c></a>', 'a/text()') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>[]
SELECT xpath('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b><b>b3</b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c></a>', 'a/b/text()') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>["b1","b2","b3"]
SELECT xpath('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b><b>b3</b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c></a>', 'a/c/text()') FROM src LIMIT 1;
>["c1","c2"]
```